# Can my Order Details table only have foreign keys?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

Here's the part of my ERD:
[image]

As you can see, the OrderID from the Order Details table is inherited from the Orders table's OrderID. The same goes for ProductID only in the products table. I thought I read somewhere that every table needs a primary key, however is this the exception?

Comment: If you can uniquely address any one particular row in the table, you don't need a primary id. Think: *Can I delete any one particular row uniquely?* If the answer is already *yes* and there's no other reason to have an extra id, then don't.

Comment: (orderid,productid) looks like an excellent *natural* candidate key. It could be promoted to primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Under no circumstances should your order details table use only FKS. This is a recipe for total disaster.

Order details must record the information about the product at the time of the order. For instance, price changes over time. You do not want the past orders prices to change because the price has changed going forward.

Not only will this cause issues if an ill-timed price change causes a customer to be unexpectedly charged more for something that did not ship immediately, but it will totally destroy any financial integrity of your information for reporting sales and may send bad data to your accounting system.

Orders and order details are temporal data. Everything about an order must be recorded as of the time of the actual order. This is not denormalization, temporal data is handed differently.